# c# Is there a way to write code inside of program.cs?

Tags: c#

Ok i might sound really stupid here but. I have a list, lets call it example

```
List<string> example = new List<string>();            
example.Add("abc123");
//...
```

and everytime the user runs the program it detects an input

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

and i want it so that if it detects something new that isnt in the list it will add it to the list.

or is there a workaround like putting the words in a different txt file and it can just write it onto said file and putting it on the list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `or is there a workaround like putting the words in a different txt file` - that's not "a workaround" - that's the way you're supposed to do it. trust me, you ***do not*** want to edit your program binary in any way.

Comment: Franz Gleichmann, Alright lemme try i haven't really thought of that until i was making this post. Thanks

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. of course ther e is a way to write code inside of program.cs . that's a source code file so it is meant to be filled with code. are you asking if it is possible to get text from a file instead of getting it through the console? absolutely.

Comment: search for "how to read and write to a text file in c#". Then you can create the list on program start by reading from the text file, and write new entries to the text file as needed during program execution.

Comment: Rufus L, thanks i figured it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who has encountered the same problem as mine. You could just put the items you want to put in your list to a different txt file. and then

```cs
string example = Console.ReadLine();

string savedExample =  Environment.NewLine + example;
List<string> exampleList = File.ReadAllLines("listOfItems.txt").ToList();
```

and to add your item into the list

```cs
 File.AppendAllText(@"listOfItems.txt", savedExample);
```

It will add example into the list which is the users input.
The `Environment.NewLine` is to add a new line so the program wont just keep writing on the same line

Note: the `listOfItems.txt` is expected to be in the same file path as your program.cs or simply you can replace it with a path

(edit because i forgot to mention): make sure your `listOfItems.txt` is something like

```cs
hello
abc123
test
example
//and so on
```

and not something like

```cs
exampleList.Add("hello");
exampleList.Add("abc123");
//...
```